# What are the consequences of a minimum wage increase to £10 p/h?

Tags: united-kingdom, minimum-wage

Throughout the UK election Jeremy Corbyn and Labour had in their manifesto to [raise the minimum wage to £10 p/h](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/john-mcdonnell-labour-minimum-wage-basic-universal-income-a7330451.html):

> The shadow chancellor told his party's conference in Liverpool that he would task a new body to set the wage at an appropriate level, which studies have suggested would be above £10.

The same policies were implicated by Bernie Sanders throughout the presidential election with him fighting for the $15 minimum wage. But, to keep things simple I'll stick to the UK for now.

The [current national living wage](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=1902) is at £7.50 p/h for over 25s. Which if the £10 p/h increase was implemented, I would say is a significant increase in [comparison to recent years](https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates):

- 2016 - £7.20 p/h
- 2015 - £6.70 p/h
- 2014 - £6.50 p/h

What are the consequences of such an increase in minimum wage? Wouldn't it hit [small businesses](http://www.yourdictionary.com/small-business) hard?

Comment: No body knows ahead of time, but consider this. Lowering the minimum wage to £0.1 an hour would result in unemployment level dropping to 0%. Rising the minimum wage to  £100000 an hour would result in official unemployment reaching 100%. Now, you could plot a curve between those two points. Every increase would result in stepping towards 100% unemployment level. The thing is, around £7.50 an hour the line could be steep or flat. Rise in minimum wage could significantly increase unemployment level or not at all. Politician are just arguing about the shape of the curve.

Comment: @Tlen This is a quite drastic oversimplification. There are lots of countries with no minimum wage which still have unemployment.

Comment: @Philipp would you consider hiring a person to clean your apartment for £100,000 a month? No. £1,000? No. £100? Maybe. £1? yes. Lowering minimum wage would erase classical unemployment. If one chooses to drop out of the labor market and no longer seeks employment, he is not counted as unemployed. I recommend "Out of Work: Unemployment and Government in the Twentieth-Century America" by economists Richard Vedder and Lowell Gallawa.

Comment: Didn't we already have questions that overviewed research into minimum wage here or on Skeptics? IIRC the summary is "there's conflicting research, more research needs to be funded :)"

Comment: @Tlen Frictional unemployment will still exist. If I lose my job, I'm not going to just take another one flipping burgers, I'm going to live off of my emergency fund for up to 6 months and be unemployed until I find a position with the right compensation, work, and company culture.

Comment: @Tlen "would you consider hiring a person to clean your apartment for £1 a month?"  Sure, but that doesn't mean that I would be able to find someone who would be willing to take the job at that rate.  Most people would pass that job by and *continue to look for work* that pays enough money for them to provide for themselves and their families.

Comment: @phoog - minimum wage jobs (real ones, not $15 ones) are designed for young people who enter job market and the purpose of the job is to earn extra bit of money **and get work experience**. I'd rather hire 22 YO who held a job for 5 years and knows how to do a job than a 22 YO who never has and doesn't get the concepts of "showing up on time", "dressing the part", "responsibility" etc...

Comment: @user4012 designed by whom?  If anyone were designing jobs for such a purpose, or perhaps more pertinently, a minimum wage level, they would make the minimum dependent on the employee's age (as it is in some jurisdictions, notably for the purpose of this question including the UK, but not in the majority of those with which I am familiar).  So if you follow the link in the question you'll see that the £7.50 hourly wage is decidedly not designed for young people entering the job market.

Comment: @phoog - bad wording on my part. Not so much 'designed' as 'evolved' I guess. Point being, young kids need work experience more than they need the money if you look at aggregate long term level (at a college level it's provided by internships which work exactly on the same principle, just more tailored to one's speciality as far as training as well as general workforce)

Comment: To echo @user4012, it still appears to be a case of "it is complicated and there's still a lot of conflicting research". Only last week two major reports came out saying very different things about Seattle's minimum wage hike: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/26/business/economy/seattle-minimum-wage.html?mcubz=0

Comment: @user4012 your definition of "real minimum wage jobs" is valid if it was 1978. But times have changed--drastically. That argument simply doesn't hold water anymore.

Comment: @blip the main difference between 1978 and now supports abolition of minimum wage - namely the availability of meaningful and reasonably cheap automation. If I pay more for a human by law than a machine would cost me, bye bye human job. Permanently. That worker you claim to care about lost 100% income whereas they could have only lose 10-20. Nobody can force an employer to keep employees at cost

Comment: @user4012 That implies technological automation wouldn't have happened otherwise, which is also rather silly. But that wasn't the point. Point is we have a drastically different employment landscape in this country than we had a few generations back. Most households now need two incomes. Manufacturing jobs have plummeted. Housing prices. Medical/insurance costs/needs. Etc. It's just a very different world.

Comment: @blip  That's incorrect.  Both studies show the same thing.  The $9.47 to $11 change had a modest decline of hours that did not reach statistical significance.  One study went on to evaluate the $11-$13 change and found a large decline in hours.  The other didn't evaluate that period.  It's only a conflict in that they looked at different things.  But when you look at their actual claims, there is no conflict.  It's also worth noting that one study looked only at food services while the other looked at everything.  There are reasons why food services might better stand local wage increases.

Comment: @Tlen The UK (the primary subject of the question) did not have a minimum wage until *c.* 20 years ago, and yet British unemployment was most certainly not invented in 1998. The assumption by many at the time, incl. far-future PM, David Cameron, was that it "would send unemployment straight back up", but this didn't materialise and, after it was introduced he admitted that "the minimum wage has been a success, yes. It turned out much better than many people expected".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Seattle increased the minimum wage](https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-06-26/seattle-s-painful-lesson-on-the-road-to-a-15-minimum-wage) from $9.47 to $11 an hour and then from $11 to $13 an hour.  In the $9.47 to $11 an hour increase income outweighed employment losses to produce an average increase in earnings (about $24 a month).  The $11 to $13 increase produced the opposite effect.  It not only decreased average earnings ($125 a month), but it did so enough to wipe out the increase from $9.47 to $11.

How does this compare to the Labour proposal?  £10 is roughly $13 and £7.50 is roughly $9.74 under the current exchange rate.  If the United Kingdom is similar to Seattle (in the United States), the proposed increase would reduce average earnings because hours would drop more than hourly wages would increase.

It's worth noting that Seattle is in a relatively high wage area of the US.  While there are a couple other cities that might do better, like New York City and San Francisco, many regions would not.  For example, $15 is higher than the *median* wage in most of the South.  That said, the UK is a different country, and wages are more likely to be comparable to Seattle there than in the rural South US.

Note that even the $9.47 to $11 increase caused hours to drop.  It just caused the hourly wage to increase enough to offset that on average.  That's fine for those whose pay goes up.  It's kind of hard on those whose hours are cut or worse, eliminated.  This is important, because people who lose their jobs entirely can't get better jobs.  They have to sit around and wait for an opening in the same lousy jobs from which they were laid off.

The problem is of course that the first people laid off tend to be those with the least experience.  I.e. the ones who have the most trouble finding new jobs.  The UK's separate rules for those under 25 may help with that, but in the US, the places with the highest minimum wage also tend to have the highest youth unemployment.

It's noteworthy that Denmark has high wages, a robust safety net, and [no statutory minimum wage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minimum_wages_by_country).  Its "minimum wage" is set on an industry by industry basis through agreements between employers and unions.  Sweden, Norway, and Finland operate similarly.

And these are the short term effects.  Longer term it's possible that labor might be replaced with automation, even at the $11 level.  And of course, the money has to come from somewhere.  Short term that might be ownership.  Longer term, it is likely to come in the form of higher prices.  As a general rule, owners have more investment options than consumers have purchase options.

Comment: It needs to be noted that two respected research results came out this past week about Seattle...and they had conflicting results: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/26/business/economy/seattle-minimum-wage.html?mcubz=0 (TL/DR: it's complicated and there is still conflicting data)

Comment: Never understood why this is a complicated question. No matter who is working, if that person's production stays the same, that means the value of what they produce stays the same.  Minimum wage simply assigns an arbitrary value to the base production.  And further, values any production below the arbitrary "floor" the same.  In the end if you raise wages from 7 to 8 then new(8) = old(7)

Comment: It would also be worth noting the closing down of businesses that can not longer function because of the hours decrease you've mentioned. http://www.facesof15.com/ has a map of all businesses(usually small) that have either been affected or shut down because of the sudden increase in wages.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum wage is already pricing labour costs well above what supply/demand would have set it at, a further increase will just see automated solutions become more appealing to employers than they already are.

We are already seeing self service checkouts in supermarkets, self-service order/payment points in fast food restaurants.

Basically a lot of the low skilled jobs that would be effected by minimum wage laws can be easily automated so i would expect to see more investment in these technologies.

if you increase the price of something you will lower the demand for it. Labour is no different.

Comment: In theory, this is correct. In practice, take a look at how &**&^*y automated self service checkouts are (that may change in near future; but it's nowhere near production ready now). Given current mininum wage levels, cashiers are still cheaper than automated checkouts that produce equal customer satisfaction/speed.

Comment: @user4012 higher labor costs will drive investment into these technologies.

Comment: This isn't necessarily incorrect, but hardly comprehensive. This is a simplification of but one aspect of the issue.

Comment: @user1450877 - again, theoretically, yes. Practically, we invested in fusion energy for decades with zero results. AI only became somewhat usable very recently despite decades if investment and research. You can't assume the cost of developing a specific technology is always less than the cost of labor - it depends on specific situation